# rotate only the image not the matrix

Tags: kivy

I want to load an image, rotate (because the image is vertical) and code after independent of the rotation (continuously moving right)

I can rotate an image and continue coding, but after that the image will have an unexpected behaviour (it start to move upward instead of right)

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.graphics import Rectangle, Rotate, Color
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.graphics import PushMatrix, PopMatrix



class Trunk(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        print(self.size, self.center)
        self.pos = 500, 500
        self.size = 200, 100
        with self.canvas.before:
            PushMatrix()
            Rotate(angle=90, axis=(0, 0, 1), origin=self.center)
            self.rect = Rectangle(pos=self.pos, size=self.size)
            self.bind(pos=self.update_rect)

        with self.canvas.after:
            PopMatrix()

    def update_rect(self, *args):
        self.rect.pos = self.pos 


class Game(Widget):
    pass

    def update(self, dt):
        self.children[0].x += .5

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        game = Game()
        trunk = Trunk()

        game.add_widget(trunk)
        Clock.schedule_interval(game.update, 1.0 / 60)

        return game

TestApp().run()
```

I expect that the rectangle go right (self.children[0].x += .5) because I'm increasing the x,

Thank you

Comment: I'm not familiar with kivy, but in the framework I use, one would rotate matrix, draw the image you want rotated, and then restore the matrix to the orientation it had before.

Comment: I already tried that, but it didn't work, thank you

Comment: I think it's an issue that your Rotate origin doesn't move along with your image. Try updating that when the pos changes.

Comment: I created another Widget (hit box) and works fine, if not I can only rotate the image not the original widget and the hit box is bad (vertical instead of horizontal), so I think is the way to go, thank you all

ps: I do in .kv @inclement so that doesn't apply, but you are right, I try first in .py and I need to add that line (self.children[0].rot.origin = self.children[0].center)